# embedded or "join" when the array sub_field is not always read or updated

Tags: mongodb, database-schema

I am designing a mongodb schema for the "Comments" part for a Post but unlike the typical design, the comments of a post are not always needed i.e. in most case we show post only and will only show the related comments when switch to a different screen. So we have decided to move the Comments subfield to a different collections.

However there are still two choices:

1. a single Comments object per post, with an array sub-field in it, to store all comments.
2. a number of Comment objects per post

I guess with 1 the read is faster (but I am not sure whether this is strictly correct if we index post_id as well in 2 ) but slower when write (as we have to save the whole document - array of comments, when you dont have to e.g. when you just add 1 new comment)

what are the (other) keys thing I should take into account as well?

Comment: This is really way "too broad" a question to reasonably answer here. There is already respectible reading on your exact subject in the MongoDB documentation [right here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/data-modeling/).

Comment: I disagree, the mongodb document only discuss on the 'naive' case where posts always come with comments (i.e. they are needed at the same time). The argument here is: how much performance gain we can have if we include an array of documents instead of 'distributing' the documents (while the benefit of including them is not 'naively' obvious)

Comment: I kind of disagree with "as we have to save the whole document - array of comments, when you dont have to e.g. when you just add 1 new comment.".  As per MongoDB: The Definitive Guide, Second Edition
by Kristina Chodorow, in-place update of arrays is possible. Excerpt - "Usually only certain portions of a document need to be updated. You can update specific fields in a document using atomic update modifiers. Update modifiers are special keys that can be used to specify complex update operations, such as altering, adding, or removing keys, and even manipulating arrays and embedded documents."

Answer (score 0):

I think that putting all the comments into an array within a larger object only makes sense if that larger object itself is a meaningful unit.  For example, if that larger object is the post itself.  But just having a container object for all the comments would not buy you anything – reading would not be significantly faster than getting all the comments with a query on post_id, and the hassle of having to grow or update an array within another document is not worth it.  The comments should all be separate documents in your case, I think.

Comment: when I think it twice, I realised the performance improvement of having a container can be significant (if we have a large number of comment entries)? because we will have to seek the disk n times to get all n 'in-scope' comments although we have index in place (only help identify which one to take but we are still read them from different part of the disk)?

Comment: unless mongodb has already done someting to optimize this kind of query?

Comment: If the comments are not in RAM already, then yes, faulting them in from disk one by one might take considerable time.  But if you have a working set of posts and their comments that is always in RAM, then the difference would be negligible.